# Finite Automata -- Determine if a set is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

I have been at this for hours. The question is:

> Prove that the language $A = \{0^kx \mid k > 0, x \in \{0,1\}^*, \text{ and } \#(0,x) \geq k\}$ is regular,
>
> where $\#(n, x)$ denotes the number of $n$ in string $x$.

So far, I have used the pumping lemma to determine that the opposite is not regular, i.e. that if $\#(0,x) \leq k$, the language is not regular.

I have also constructed a nondeterministic finite automaton that I thought I could use to prove that this set is regular since that is generally the way to go about proving regularity. I can't really draw it, but at start state $s$, if $0$ is read in, then move to state 1 (or state $'0'$). If a $0$ is read in, either stay in state 1 or move to state 2. If a $1$ is read in, move to state 2. However, I honestly don't know what to do further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that a word belongs to $A$ iff it starts at $0$ and contains at least one more $0$. That is, $A$ is accepted by the regular expression $01^*0(0+1)^*$.

Comment: Ah ok. So in essence, we are constructing a DFA with three states $s$, $1$, and $2$ where $s$ -> $1$ if a zero is read in (and an 'inaccessible' state if a one is read in), $1$ -> $1$ if a one is read in, $1$ -> $2$ if a zero is read in, and $2$ -> $2$ if either a one or a zero is read in, with $2$ being the accept state?

Comment: DFAs don't have inaccessible states, but otherwise you're right. Make sure that you know why $A$ consists exactly of these words, and that you can prove it is so.

Comment: Does the proof of why A consists exactly of these words involve the DFA's delta and delta-hat functions?

Comment: The proof is independent of the DFA. You have to show that a word is of the form $0^k x$, where $k > 0$ and $x$ contains at least $k$ zeroes, iff it starts with $0$ and contains at least two zeroes.

Comment: Ok. So basically I have down this: suppose for w in A that w does not begin with a zero and contain at least two 0s. Thus, we have three cases: w begins with a 1 and #(0,w) >= 2, w begins with a 1 and #(0, w) < 2, and w begins with a 0 and #(0,w) < 2. The first two cases are trivially false, as A is defined as beginning with a zero. For the third case, with w begins with a zero, k = 1 at this point in time. Since k=1, x must have, by definition, at least one zero, bringing the total number of zeroes to at least 2, thereby invalidating the case. Thus, the #(0,w) >= 2, w begins with a zero...

Comment: ...and A is thereby represented by the DFA, making it regular.

Comment: I'm afraid this proof is incomplete. You haven't shown that $\{0^k x : k > 0, \#(0,x) \geq 2\} = \{0w : \#(0,w) \geq 1\}$. At this point, however, it is best if you finished solving the exercise on your own.